# Error Launching Tor while connecting with directory server in Kali Linux

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, debian, torcheck

I keep trying to start Tor, but I cannot fully connect to the network. I get to this error, just because it timed out:

```
cameron@kali:~/Desktop/tor-browser_en-US$ ./start-tor-browser

Launching Tor Browser Bundle for Linux in /home/cameron/Desktop/tor-browser_en-US
Jul 21 16:12:50.263 [notice] Tor v0.2.4.22 (git-345e00dc68a052fe) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable and OpenSSL 1.0.1h.
[…]
Jul 21 16:12:55.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server.
Jul 21 16:12:55.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. 
Jul 21 16:17:55.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 1; recommendation warn)
Jul 21 16:17:55.000 [warn] 1 connections have failed: 
Jul 21 16:17:55.000 [warn] 1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE
```

It says that I have connected to the Tor network from whatever they call the Vidalia now (not actually Vidalia, just what you see when you launch newest versions of Tor)... But I check http://check.torproject.org and I'm not connected. I am fully able to connect to the Tor network from my Windows OS, so my ISP isn't blocking access. If you can help, either tell me how to fix it, or tell me a new method, it would mean alot.

OS: Kali Linux 1.0.6 x64

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kali Linux. Does it have some sort of firewall which could be blocking outgoing connections?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It is just a customized version of Debian.

Comment: Does the tor service work? sudo apt-get install tor tor-arm && service tor start && arm If the service works, in Iceweasel, goto Preferences>Advanced>Network>Connection>Settings (I am on windows right now, if there is any mistake with the config path, sorry.) - Manual Proxy Configuration SOCKS Host: 127.0.0.1 (or try localhost) Port 9050 SOCKSv4 TIP: Update to Kali 1.0.8